# Saving all tables,variables, and functions of a KDB+ instance and then reloading

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Is there a simple way to save all tables,variables and fucntions and then reload them into another kdb+ instance? For example, lets say my machine is set to restart weekly but I want reload everything that was in my kdb+ session before the restart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something out of the box for maintaining variable state(tables/dicts/lists/atom), then have a look at http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/logging/

```
/cmdline startup
q db_main -l -p 8090

/To store state before the restart, modify .z.exit to flush to the qdb file 
.z.exit:{value"\\l"}
```

This will not cover functions however, but ideally these shouldn't be changing anyway.

If you really need to save these you can look at saving all namespaces to disk.

```
.z.exit:{`:/tmp/ns set get each {x!x}`$".",/:string key`}

/on startup
{{y set x[y]}[x;]each key x} `.q`.Q _ get `:/tmp/ns
```

Regards,

Connor

Answer (score 1):

Save the state to file using set/get. This is limited to small workspaces.

```
>q
KDB+ 3.4 2016.06.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2016 Kx Systems

q)a:1
q)t:([] b:til 100)
q)s:select from t where b<5
q)`:session.bin set get `.
`:session.bin
q)\\

>q
KDB+ 3.4 2016.06.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2016 Kx Systems

q)`. set get `:session.bin
`.
q)a
1
q)s
b
-
0
1
2
3
4
```

Logging and snapshots is an alternative:
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-command-line-options#kdb-logging-replication

Comment: This will work if you wish to save multiple namespaces. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38528576/2039505